# Spring Boot Zuul - Hystrix short-circuited is OPEN

Tags: spring, spring-cloud, netflix-zuul, spring-cloud-netflix, hystrix

we have some spring boot based microservices sitting behind the spring zuul gateway. At the moment we do some performance testing. We fire up 60 calls distributed over 8 seconds and the only reponses we get is "500 - Internal Server Error" with message "SHORTCIRCUITED"

We don't use spring hystrix in any of the services, but we know that all calls made by zuul are wrapped by hystrix so we tried to configure it in our gateway but nothing helped.

Here is our gateway application.yml (coming from a spring cloud config server):

```
server:
  port: 4444

ribbon:
  readtimeout: 5000
  sockettimeout: 5000
  MaxTotalConnections: 10000
  MaxConnectionsPerHost: 10000
  MaxTotalHttpConnections: 10000
  MaxAutoRetries: 5
  MaxAutoRetriesNextServer: 5

# https://github.com/spring-cloud/spring-cloud-netflix/issues/2069
zuul:
  host:
    maxTotalConnections: 10000
    maxPerRouteConnections: 10000
  ribbon:
    eager-load:
      enabled: true
  prefix: /api
  stripPrefix: false
  routes:
    auth-service-api:
      path: /auth/**
      serviceId: auth-service
      stripPrefix: false
      sensitiveHeaders:
    user-service-api:
      path: /users/**
      serviceId: user-service
      stripPrefix: false
      sensitiveHeaders:
  add-proxy-headers: true
```

The stacktrace from the log of our zuul gateway looks like the following:

```
2018-12-06 13:40:22.286  WARN 1 --- [nio-4444-exec-3] o.s.c.n.z.filters.post.SendErrorFilter   : Error during filtering

com.netflix.zuul.exception.ZuulException: Forwarding error
    at org.springframework.cloud.netflix.zuul.filters.route.RibbonRoutingFilter.handleException(RibbonRoutingFilter.java:189) ~[spring-cloud-netflix-zuul-2.0.0.RELEASE.jar!/:2.0.0.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.cloud.netflix.zuul.filters.route.RibbonRoutingFilter.forward(RibbonRoutingFilter.java:164) ~[spring-cloud-netflix-zuul-2.0.0.RELEASE.jar!/:2.0.0.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.cloud.netflix.zuul.filters.route.RibbonRoutingFilter.run(RibbonRoutingFilter.java:112) ~[spring-cloud-netflix-zuul-2.0.0.RELEASE.jar!/:2.0.0.RELEASE]
    at com.netflix.zuul.ZuulFilter.runFilter(ZuulFilter.java:117) ~[zuul-core-1.3.1.jar!/:1.3.1]
    at com.netflix.zuul.FilterProcessor.processZuulFilter(FilterProcessor.java:193) ~[zuul-core-1.3.1.jar!/:1.3.1]
    at com.netflix.zuul.FilterProcessor.runFilters(FilterProcessor.java:157) ~[zuul-core-1.3.1.jar!/:1.3.1]
    at com.netflix.zuul.FilterProcessor.route(FilterProcessor.java:118) ~[zuul-core-1.3.1.jar!/:1.3.1]
    at com.netflix.zuul.ZuulRunner.route(ZuulRunner.java:96) ~[zuul-core-1.3.1.jar!/:1.3.1]
    at com.netflix.zuul.http.ZuulServlet.route(ZuulServlet.java:116) ~[zuul-core-1.3.1.jar!/:1.3.1]
    at com.netflix.zuul.http.ZuulServlet.service(ZuulServlet.java:81) ~[zuul-core-1.3.1.jar!/:1.3.1]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.ServletWrappingController.handleRequestInternal(ServletWrappingController.java:165) [spring-webmvc-5.0.9.RELEASE.jar!/:5.0.9.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.cloud.netflix.zuul.web.ZuulController.handleRequest(ZuulController.java:44) [spring-cloud-netflix-zuul-2.0.0.RELEASE.jar!/:2.0.0.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.SimpleControllerHandlerAdapter.handle(SimpleControllerHandlerAdapter.java:52) [spring-webmvc-5.0.9.RELEASE.jar!/:5.0.9.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doDispatch(DispatcherServlet.java:991) [spring-webmvc-5.0.9.RELEASE.jar!/:5.0.9.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doService(DispatcherServlet.java:925) [spring-webmvc-5.0.9.RELEASE.jar!/:5.0.9.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.processRequest(FrameworkServlet.java:974) [spring-webmvc-5.0.9.RELEASE.jar!/:5.0.9.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.doPost(FrameworkServlet.java:877) [spring-webmvc-5.0.9.RELEASE.jar!/:5.0.9.RELEASE]
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:661) [tomcat-embed-core-8.5.34.jar!/:8.5.34]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.service(FrameworkServlet.java:851) [spring-webmvc-5.0.9.RELEASE.jar!/:5.0.9.RELEASE]
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:742) [tomcat-embed-core-8.5.34.jar!/:8.5.34]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:231) [tomcat-embed-core-8.5.34.jar!/:8.5.34]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166) [tomcat-embed-core-8.5.34.jar!/:8.5.34]
    at org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:52) [tomcat-embed-websocket-8.5.34.jar!/:8.5.34]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193) [tomcat-embed-core-8.5.34.jar!/:8.5.34]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166) [tomcat-embed-core-8.5.34.jar!/:8.5.34]
    at org.springframework.boot.actuate.web.trace.servlet.HttpTraceFilter.doFilterInternal(HttpTraceFilter.java:90) [spring-boot-actuator-2.0.5.RELEASE.jar!/:2.0.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107) [spring-web-5.0.9.RELEASE.jar!/:5.0.9.RELEASE]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193) [tomcat-embed-core-8.5.34.jar!/:8.5.34]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166) [tomcat-embed-core-8.5.34.jar!/:8.5.34]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.RequestContextFilter.doFilterInternal(RequestContextFilter.java:99) [spring-web-5.0.9.RELEASE.jar!/:5.0.9.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107) [spring-web-5.0.9.RELEASE.jar!/:5.0.9.RELEASE]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193) [tomcat-embed-core-8.5.34.jar!/:8.5.34]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166) [tomcat-embed-core-8.5.34.jar!/:8.5.34]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.HttpPutFormContentFilter.doFilterInternal(HttpPutFormContentFilter.java:109) [spring-web-5.0.9.RELEASE.jar!/:5.0.9.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107) [spring-web-5.0.9.RELEASE.jar!/:5.0.9.RELEASE]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193) [tomcat-embed-core-8.5.34.jar!/:8.5.34]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166) [tomcat-embed-core-8.5.34.jar!/:8.5.34]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.HiddenHttpMethodFilter.doFilterInternal(HiddenHttpMethodFilter.java:93) [spring-web-5.0.9.RELEASE.jar!/:5.0.9.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107) [spring-web-5.0.9.RELEASE.jar!/:5.0.9.RELEASE]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193) [tomcat-embed-core-8.5.34.jar!/:8.5.34]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166) [tomcat-embed-core-8.5.34.jar!/:8.5.34]
    at org.springframework.boot.actuate.metrics.web.servlet.WebMvcMetricsFilter.filterAndRecordMetrics(WebMvcMetricsFilter.java:155) [spring-boot-actuator-2.0.5.RELEASE.jar!/:2.0.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.actuate.metrics.web.servlet.WebMvcMetricsFilter.filterAndRecordMetrics(WebMvcMetricsFilter.java:123) [spring-boot-actuator-2.0.5.RELEASE.jar!/:2.0.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.actuate.metrics.web.servlet.WebMvcMetricsFilter.doFilterInternal(WebMvcMetricsFilter.java:108) [spring-boot-actuator-2.0.5.RELEASE.jar!/:2.0.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107) [spring-web-5.0.9.RELEASE.jar!/:5.0.9.RELEASE]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193) [tomcat-embed-core-8.5.34.jar!/:8.5.34]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166) [tomcat-embed-core-8.5.34.jar!/:8.5.34]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.CharacterEncodingFilter.doFilterInternal(CharacterEncodingFilter.java:200) [spring-web-5.0.9.RELEASE.jar!/:5.0.9.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107) [spring-web-5.0.9.RELEASE.jar!/:5.0.9.RELEASE]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193) [tomcat-embed-core-8.5.34.jar!/:8.5.34]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166) [tomcat-embed-core-8.5.34.jar!/:8.5.34]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:198) [tomcat-embed-core-8.5.34.jar!/:8.5.34]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:96) [tomcat-embed-core-8.5.34.jar!/:8.5.34]
    at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:493) [tomcat-embed-core-8.5.34.jar!/:8.5.34]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:140) [tomcat-embed-core-8.5.34.jar!/:8.5.34]
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:81) [tomcat-embed-core-8.5.34.jar!/:8.5.34]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:87) [tomcat-embed-core-8.5.34.jar!/:8.5.34]
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:342) [tomcat-embed-core-8.5.34.jar!/:8.5.34]
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Processor.service(Http11Processor.java:800) [tomcat-embed-core-8.5.34.jar!/:8.5.34]
    at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProcessorLight.process(AbstractProcessorLight.java:66) [tomcat-embed-core-8.5.34.jar!/:8.5.34]
    at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$ConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:806) [tomcat-embed-core-8.5.34.jar!/:8.5.34]
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$SocketProcessor.doRun(NioEndpoint.java:1498) [tomcat-embed-core-8.5.34.jar!/:8.5.34]
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.SocketProcessorBase.run(SocketProcessorBase.java:49) [tomcat-embed-core-8.5.34.jar!/:8.5.34]
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1149) [na:1.8.0_171]
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:624) [na:1.8.0_171]
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.TaskThread$WrappingRunnable.run(TaskThread.java:61) [tomcat-embed-core-8.5.34.jar!/:8.5.34]
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748) [na:1.8.0_171]
Caused by: com.netflix.hystrix.exception.HystrixRuntimeException: auth-service short-circuited and no fallback available.
    at com.netflix.hystrix.AbstractCommand$22.call(AbstractCommand.java:819) ~[hystrix-core-1.5.12.jar!/:1.5.12]
    at com.netflix.hystrix.AbstractCommand$22.call(AbstractCommand.java:804) ~[hystrix-core-1.5.12.jar!/:1.5.12]
    at rx.internal.operators.OperatorOnErrorResumeNextViaFunction$4.onError(OperatorOnErrorResumeNextViaFunction.java:140) ~[rxjava-1.2.0.jar!/:1.2.0]
    at rx.internal.operators.OnSubscribeDoOnEach$DoOnEachSubscriber.onError(OnSubscribeDoOnEach.java:87) ~[rxjava-1.2.0.jar!/:1.2.0]
    at rx.internal.operators.OnSubscribeDoOnEach$DoOnEachSubscriber.onError(OnSubscribeDoOnEach.java:87) ~[rxjava-1.2.0.jar!/:1.2.0]
    at com.netflix.hystrix.AbstractCommand$DeprecatedOnFallbackHookApplication$1.onError(AbstractCommand.java:1472) ~[hystrix-core-1.5.12.jar!/:1.5.12]
    at com.netflix.hystrix.AbstractCommand$FallbackHookApplication$1.onError(AbstractCommand.java:1397) ~[hystrix-core-1.5.12.jar!/:1.5.12]
    at rx.internal.operators.OnSubscribeDoOnEach$DoOnEachSubscriber.onError(OnSubscribeDoOnEach.java:87) ~[rxjava-1.2.0.jar!/:1.2.0]
    at rx.observers.Subscribers$5.onError(Subscribers.java:230) ~[rxjava-1.2.0.jar!/:1.2.0]
    at rx.internal.operators.OnSubscribeThrow.call(OnSubscribeThrow.java:44) ~[rxjava-1.2.0.jar!/:1.2.0]
    at rx.internal.operators.OnSubscribeThrow.call(OnSubscribeThrow.java:28) ~[rxjava-1.2.0.jar!/:1.2.0]
    at rx.Observable.unsafeSubscribe(Observable.java:10151) ~[rxjava-1.2.0.jar!/:1.2.0]
    at rx.internal.operators.OnSubscribeDefer.call(OnSubscribeDefer.java:51) ~[rxjava-1.2.0.jar!/:1.2.0]
    at rx.internal.operators.OnSubscribeDefer.call(OnSubscribeDefer.java:35) ~[rxjava-1.2.0.jar!/:1.2.0]
    at rx.Observable.unsafeSubscribe(Observable.java:10151) ~[rxjava-1.2.0.jar!/:1.2.0]
    at rx.internal.operators.OnSubscribeDoOnEach.call(OnSubscribeDoOnEach.java:41) ~[rxjava-1.2.0.jar!/:1.2.0]
    at rx.internal.operators.OnSubscribeDoOnEach.call(OnSubscribeDoOnEach.java:30) ~[rxjava-1.2.0.jar!/:1.2.0]
    at rx.internal.operators.OnSubscribeLift.call(OnSubscribeLift.java:48) ~[rxjava-1.2.0.jar!/:1.2.0]
    at rx.internal.operators.OnSubscribeLift.call(OnSubscribeLift.java:30) ~[rxjava-1.2.0.jar!/:1.2.0]
    at rx.internal.operators.OnSubscribeLift.call(OnSubscribeLift.java:48) ~[rxjava-1.2.0.jar!/:1.2.0]
    at rx.internal.operators.OnSubscribeLift.call(OnSubscribeLift.java:30) ~[rxjava-1.2.0.jar!/:1.2.0]
    at rx.Observable.unsafeSubscribe(Observable.java:10151) ~[rxjava-1.2.0.jar!/:1.2.0]
    at rx.internal.operators.OnSubscribeDoOnEach.call(OnSubscribeDoOnEach.java:41) ~[rxjava-1.2.0.jar!/:1.2.0]
    at rx.internal.operators.OnSubscribeDoOnEach.call(OnSubscribeDoOnEach.java:30) ~[rxjava-1.2.0.jar!/:1.2.0]
    at rx.Observable.unsafeSubscribe(Observable.java:10151) ~[rxjava-1.2.0.jar!/:1.2.0]
    at rx.internal.operators.OnSubscribeDoOnEach.call(OnSubscribeDoOnEach.java:41) ~[rxjava-1.2.0.jar!/:1.2.0]
    at rx.internal.operators.OnSubscribeDoOnEach.call(OnSubscribeDoOnEach.java:30) ~[rxjava-1.2.0.jar!/:1.2.0]
    at rx.internal.operators.OnSubscribeLift.call(OnSubscribeLift.java:48) ~[rxjava-1.2.0.jar!/:1.2.0]
    at rx.internal.operators.OnSubscribeLift.call(OnSubscribeLift.java:30) ~[rxjava-1.2.0.jar!/:1.2.0]
    at rx.Observable.unsafeSubscribe(Observable.java:10151) ~[rxjava-1.2.0.jar!/:1.2.0]
    at rx.internal.operators.OnSubscribeDoOnEach.call(OnSubscribeDoOnEach.java:41) ~[rxjava-1.2.0.jar!/:1.2.0]
    at rx.internal.operators.OnSubscribeDoOnEach.call(OnSubscribeDoOnEach.java:30) ~[rxjava-1.2.0.jar!/:1.2.0]
    at rx.internal.operators.OnSubscribeLift.call(OnSubscribeLift.java:48) ~[rxjava-1.2.0.jar!/:1.2.0]
    at rx.internal.operators.OnSubscribeLift.call(OnSubscribeLift.java:30) ~[rxjava-1.2.0.jar!/:1.2.0]
    at rx.Observable.unsafeSubscribe(Observable.java:10151) ~[rxjava-1.2.0.jar!/:1.2.0]
    at rx.internal.operators.OnSubscribeDefer.call(OnSubscribeDefer.java:51) ~[rxjava-1.2.0.jar!/:1.2.0]
    at rx.internal.operators.OnSubscribeDefer.call(OnSubscribeDefer.java:35) ~[rxjava-1.2.0.jar!/:1.2.0]
    at rx.Observable.unsafeSubscribe(Observable.java:10151) ~[rxjava-1.2.0.jar!/:1.2.0]
    at rx.internal.operators.OnSubscribeMap.call(OnSubscribeMap.java:48) ~[rxjava-1.2.0.jar!/:1.2.0]
    at rx.internal.operators.OnSubscribeMap.call(OnSubscribeMap.java:33) ~[rxjava-1.2.0.jar!/:1.2.0]
    at rx.Observable.unsafeSubscribe(Observable.java:10151) ~[rxjava-1.2.0.jar!/:1.2.0]
    at rx.internal.operators.OnSubscribeDoOnEach.call(OnSubscribeDoOnEach.java:41) ~[rxjava-1.2.0.jar!/:1.2.0]
    at rx.internal.operators.OnSubscribeDoOnEach.call(OnSubscribeDoOnEach.java:30) ~[rxjava-1.2.0.jar!/:1.2.0]
    at rx.internal.operators.OnSubscribeLift.call(OnSubscribeLift.java:48) ~[rxjava-1.2.0.jar!/:1.2.0]
    at rx.internal.operators.OnSubscribeLift.call(OnSubscribeLift.java:30) ~[rxjava-1.2.0.jar!/:1.2.0]
    at rx.Observable.unsafeSubscribe(Observable.java:10151) ~[rxjava-1.2.0.jar!/:1.2.0]
    at rx.internal.operators.OnSubscribeDoOnEach.call(OnSubscribeDoOnEach.java:41) ~[rxjava-1.2.0.jar!/:1.2.0]
    at rx.internal.operators.OnSubscribeDoOnEach.call(OnSubscribeDoOnEach.java:30) ~[rxjava-1.2.0.jar!/:1.2.0]
    at rx.Observable.unsafeSubscribe(Observable.java:10151) ~[rxjava-1.2.0.jar!/:1.2.0]
    at rx.internal.operators.OnSubscribeDefer.call(OnSubscribeDefer.java:51) ~[rxjava-1.2.0.jar!/:1.2.0]
    at rx.internal.operators.OnSubscribeDefer.call(OnSubscribeDefer.java:35) ~[rxjava-1.2.0.jar!/:1.2.0]
    at rx.internal.operators.OnSubscribeLift.call(OnSubscribeLift.java:48) ~[rxjava-1.2.0.jar!/:1.2.0]
    at rx.internal.operators.OnSubscribeLift.call(OnSubscribeLift.java:30) ~[rxjava-1.2.0.jar!/:1.2.0]
    at rx.Observable.subscribe(Observable.java:10247) ~[rxjava-1.2.0.jar!/:1.2.0]
    at rx.Observable.subscribe(Observable.java:10214) ~[rxjava-1.2.0.jar!/:1.2.0]
    at rx.internal.operators.BlockingOperatorToFuture.toFuture(BlockingOperatorToFuture.java:51) ~[rxjava-1.2.0.jar!/:1.2.0]
    at rx.observables.BlockingObservable.toFuture(BlockingObservable.java:411) ~[rxjava-1.2.0.jar!/:1.2.0]
    at com.netflix.hystrix.HystrixCommand.queue(HystrixCommand.java:378) ~[hystrix-core-1.5.12.jar!/:1.5.12]
    at com.netflix.hystrix.HystrixCommand.execute(HystrixCommand.java:344) ~[hystrix-core-1.5.12.jar!/:1.5.12]
    at org.springframework.cloud.netflix.zuul.filters.route.RibbonRoutingFilter.forward(RibbonRoutingFilter.java:159) ~[spring-cloud-netflix-zuul-2.0.0.RELEASE.jar!/:2.0.0.RELEASE]
    ... 65 common frames omitted
Caused by: java.lang.RuntimeException: Hystrix circuit short-circuited and is OPEN
    at com.netflix.hystrix.AbstractCommand.handleShortCircuitViaFallback(AbstractCommand.java:979) ~[hystrix-core-1.5.12.jar!/:1.5.12]
    at com.netflix.hystrix.AbstractCommand.applyHystrixSemantics(AbstractCommand.java:557) ~[hystrix-core-1.5.12.jar!/:1.5.12]
    at com.netflix.hystrix.AbstractCommand.access$200(AbstractCommand.java:60) ~[hystrix-core-1.5.12.jar!/:1.5.12]
    at com.netflix.hystrix.AbstractCommand$4.call(AbstractCommand.java:419) ~[hystrix-core-1.5.12.jar!/:1.5.12]
    at com.netflix.hystrix.AbstractCommand$4.call(AbstractCommand.java:413) ~[hystrix-core-1.5.12.jar!/:1.5.12]
    at rx.internal.operators.OnSubscribeDefer.call(OnSubscribeDefer.java:46) ~[rxjava-1.2.0.jar!/:1.2.0]
    ... 89 common frames omitted
```

The auth-service uses the user-service to request whether an user already exists or not.

Does anyone know how to fix the problem can provide any other useful hints for configuring hystrix in zuul?

Thanks!

Comment: It means many failures happened over a short period of time triggering the circuit to open. Have you looked at the data via /hystrix.stream (maybe via hystrix dashboard) to see when you are having failures?

Comment: We now upgraded to spring cloud finchley sr2 and the error message changed to: 504, gateway timeout, com.netflix.zuul.exception.ZuulException: Hystrix Readed time out. We already googled and found only this https://github.com/spring-cloud/spring-cloud-netflix/issues/3289 which seems to be exactly our problem. Does anyone know something about this problem and can provide help?

Comment: We asked for a project to reproduce the problem and one was not produced. Can you provide one?

Answer (score 0):

In Zuul, hystrix is enabled and can not be disabled.

"SHORTCIRCUITED" can be opened by timeout or exception. Before performance test first, do basic test first.

Comment: Thanks for your answer! We already did basic test. We can access all APIs via Frontend and everything works fine. It even works when we fire up 5 users at once, but it seems as there is a 'magic border' because with 6 users at once all calls fail. Do you have any other suggestions?

Comment: @ManuelHoffmann we come across same issue. did you get any solution ?

Comment: No, sry, we also didn't find a solution for that.